# How to itemize greek letters?

Tags: itemize, greek, letters

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I have a problem when making a list of greek letters. This is the code down below.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \kappa
    \item \iota 
    \item \lambda
\end{itemize}
```

The error message says:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.242   \item \kappa
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You also can load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}`  and typeset the real Greek etters from your keyboard,  like this `κ, ι, λ`, or even compile with `xelatex` and load `fontspec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greek letters are supposed to appear in math-mode only. Surround the greek letters with `\(...\)`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \(\kappa\)
    \item \(\iota\)
    \item \(\lambda\)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The `! Missing $ inserted.` means, in a more wordy version: "A command that requires math-mode was found outside math-mode. I inserted a `$` to try to fix things."

(Surrounding with `$...$` is the TeX equivalent of surrounding with `\(...\)`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to typeset Greek letters in text mode, I suggest you load the `textgreek` package and type `\textalpha`, `\textbeta`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textalpha
\item \textbeta
\item \textgamma
\item \textdelta
\item \dots
\item \textpsi
\item \textomega
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Of course, there's also `\textAlpha`, `\textBeta`, ..., `\textPsi`, and `\textOmega`.

Comment: (Done) +1 Useful package :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment to @Phelipe Oleinik, so here an addition:

If you need the upright greek letters in math environment use the package [upgreek](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/upgreek).

```
$\upalpha$
$\upbeta$
```

produce the lowercase greek letters while

```
$\Upalpha$
$\Upbeta$
```

produce the upright case letters. Further reading is within the documentation of upgreek.